# SQL - Select multiple table without repeated data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a two tables (table1, table2). How to select two tables in one query without repeated datas (like as image) ?
p.s inner , left , right, full , cross joins can not help :(
[image]

Comment: Is there any matching criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on this sample data through the ID values consider such a `RIGHT JOIN` among tables :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM table1 t1
 RIGHT JOIN table2 t2
    ON 20 + t1.ID = t2.ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=259f3b8f960a9fe77df420e6b9cf8276)</kbd>

P.S. : In any case JOIN is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Select table1.id,table1.name,table2.id,table2.name from table1,table2
Group by table1.id,table1.name,table2.id,table2.name
```

----Above will give you cross results like (mxn records). You need to have where clause in your query.

If you want only matching records you can add a where clause.

```
Select table1.id,table1.name,table2.id,table2.name from table1,table2
where table1.id = table2.id
Group by table1.id,table1.name,table2.id,table2.name
```

Comment: well,the first query gives multiple rows as you implied. [The second one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=6fb2f8367e514b1f2c1da046f11ccf24) gives no result at all.